# DLL load failed and module not found: should I reinstall anaconda?

Tags: anaconda, anaconda3

I have been having issues for a few days with anaconda for a few days. When I install a library it always struggles. It either doesn't recognize I installed a library like here with pandas-profiling in anaconda3 terminal:

```
Requirement already satisfied: pandas-profiling[notebook] in c:\users\antoi\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (2.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: confuse>=1.0.0 in c:\users\antoi\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from pandas-profiling[notebook]) (1.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: requests>=2.23.0 in c:\users\antoi\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from pandas-profiling[notebook]) (2.24.0)
Requirement already satisfied: joblib in c:\users\antoi\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from pandas-profiling[notebook]) (0.15.1)
Requirement already satisfied: tqdm>=4.43.0 in c:\users\antoi\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from pandas-profiling[notebook]) (4.47.0)
Requirement already satisfied: jinja2>=2.11.1 in c:\users\antoi\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from pandas-profiling[notebook]) (2.11.1)
Requirement already satisfied: ipywidgets>=7.5.1 in c:\users\antoi\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from pandas-profiling[notebook]) (7.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=1.4.1 in c:\users\antoi\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from pandas-profiling[notebook]) (1.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: visions[type_image_path]==0.4.4 in c:\users\antoi\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from pandas-profiling[notebook]) (0.4.4)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.16.0 in c:\users\antoi\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from pandas-profiling[notebook]) (1.18.5)
Requirement already satisfied: missingno>=0.4.2 in c:\users\antoi\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from pandas-profiling[notebook]) (0.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: htmlmin>=0.1.12 in c:\users\antoi\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from pandas-profiling[notebook]) (0.1.12)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas!=1.0.0,!=1.0.1,!=1.0.2,>=0.25.3 in c:\users\antoi\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from pandas-profiling[notebook]) (1.0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: phik>=0.9.10 in c:\users\antoi\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from pandas-profiling[notebook]) (0.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: tangled-up-in-unicode>=0.0.6 in c:\users\antoi\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from pandas-profiling[notebook]) (0.0.6)
Requirement already satisfied: astropy>=4.0 in c:\users\antoi\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from pandas-profiling[notebook]) (4.0.1.post1)
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib>=3.2.0 in c:\users\antoi\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from pandas-profiling[notebook]) (3.2.2)
Requirement already satisfied: jupyter-core>=4.6.3; extra == "notebook" in c:\users\antoi\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from pandas-profiling[notebook]) (4.6.3)
Requirement already satisfied: jupyter-client>=6.0.0; extra == "notebook" in c:\users\antoi\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from pandas-profiling[notebook]) (6.1.5)
Requirement already satisfied: pyyaml in c:\users\antoi\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from confuse>=1.0.0->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (5.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 in c:\users\antoi\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from requests>=2.23.0->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (1.22)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<3,>=2.5 in c:\users\antoi\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from requests>=2.23.0->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (2.6)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<4,>=3.0.2 in c:\users\antoi\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from requests>=2.23.0->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\antoi\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from requests>=2.23.0->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (2019.11.28)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=0.23 in c:\users\antoi\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from jinja2>=2.11.1->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (1.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: traitlets>=4.3.1 in c:\users\antoi\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from ipywidgets>=7.5.1->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (4.3.3)
Requirement already satisfied: widgetsnbextension~=3.5.0 in c:\users\antoi\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from ipywidgets>=7.5.1->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (3.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: ipython>=4.0.0; python_version >= "3.3" in c:\users\antoi\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from ipywidgets>=7.5.1->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (7.16.1)
Requirement already satisfied: ipykernel>=4.5.1 in c:\users\antoi\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from ipywidgets>=7.5.1->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (5.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: nbformat>=4.2.0 in c:\users\antoi\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from ipywidgets>=7.5.1->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (5.0.7)
Requirement already satisfied: attrs>=19.3.0 in c:\users\antoi\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from visions[type_image_path]==0.4.4->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (19.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: networkx>=2.4 in c:\users\antoi\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from visions[type_image_path]==0.4.4->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (2.4)
Requirement already satisfied: Pillow; extra == "type_image_path" in c:\users\antoi\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from visions[type_image_path]==0.4.4->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (7.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: imagehash; extra == "type_image_path" in c:\users\antoi\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from visions[type_image_path]==0.4.4->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (4.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: seaborn in c:\users\antoi\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from missingno>=0.4.2->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (0.10.1)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.6.1 in c:\users\antoi\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from pandas!=1.0.0,!=1.0.1,!=1.0.2,>=0.25.3->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2017.2 in c:\users\antoi\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from pandas!=1.0.0,!=1.0.1,!=1.0.2,>=0.25.3->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (2019.3)
Requirement already satisfied: numba>=0.38.1 in c:\users\antoi\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from phik>=0.9.10->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (0.50.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing!=2.0.4,!=2.1.2,!=2.1.6,>=2.0.1 in c:\users\antoi\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from matplotlib>=3.2.0->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (2.4.6)
Requirement already satisfied: kiwisolver>=1.0.1 in c:\users\antoi\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from matplotlib>=3.2.0->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in c:\users\antoi\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from matplotlib>=3.2.0->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (0.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pywin32>=1.0; sys_platform == "win32" in c:\users\antoi\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from jupyter-core>=4.6.3; extra == "notebook"->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (228)
Requirement already satisfied: pyzmq>=13 in c:\users\antoi\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from jupyter-client>=6.0.0; extra == "notebook"->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (19.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: tornado>=4.1 in c:\users\antoi\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from jupyter-client>=6.0.0; extra == "notebook"->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (6.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: ipython-genutils in c:\users\antoi\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from traitlets>=4.3.1->ipywidgets>=7.5.1->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (0.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: decorator in c:\users\antoi\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from traitlets>=4.3.1->ipywidgets>=7.5.1->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (4.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\users\antoi\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from traitlets>=4.3.1->ipywidgets>=7.5.1->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (1.14.0)
Requirement already satisfied: notebook>=4.4.1 in c:\users\antoi\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from widgetsnbextension~=3.5.0->ipywidgets>=7.5.1->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (6.0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: prompt-toolkit!=3.0.0,!=3.0.1,<3.1.0,>=2.0.0 in c:\users\antoi\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from ipython>=4.0.0; python_version >= "3.3"->ipywidgets>=7.5.1->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (2.0.10)
Requirement already satisfied: colorama; sys_platform == "win32" in c:\users\antoi\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from ipython>=4.0.0; python_version >= "3.3"->ipywidgets>=7.5.1->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (0.4.3)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=18.5 in c:\users\antoi\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from ipython>=4.0.0; python_version >= "3.3"->ipywidgets>=7.5.1->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (46.1.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pygments in c:\users\antoi\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from ipython>=4.0.0; python_version >= "3.3"->ipywidgets>=7.5.1->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (2.6.1)
Requirement already satisfied: backcall in c:\users\antoi\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from ipython>=4.0.0; python_version >= "3.3"->ipywidgets>=7.5.1->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (0.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: jedi>=0.10 in c:\users\antoi\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from ipython>=4.0.0; python_version >= "3.3"->ipywidgets>=7.5.1->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (0.17.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pickleshare in c:\users\antoi\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from ipython>=4.0.0; python_version >= "3.3"->ipywidgets>=7.5.1->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (0.7.5)
Requirement already satisfied: jsonschema!=2.5.0,>=2.4 in c:\users\antoi\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from nbformat>=4.2.0->ipywidgets>=7.5.1->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (3.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: PyWavelets in c:\users\antoi\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from imagehash; extra == "type_image_path"->visions[type_image_path]==0.4.4->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (1.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: llvmlite<0.34,>=0.33.0.dev0 in c:\users\antoi\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from numba>=0.38.1->phik>=0.9.10->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (0.33.0)
Requirement already satisfied: nbconvert in c:\users\antoi\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from notebook>=4.4.1->widgetsnbextension~=3.5.0->ipywidgets>=7.5.1->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (5.6.1)
Requirement already satisfied: prometheus-client in c:\users\antoi\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from notebook>=4.4.1->widgetsnbextension~=3.5.0->ipywidgets>=7.5.1->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (0.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: terminado>=0.8.1 in c:\users\antoi\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from notebook>=4.4.1->widgetsnbextension~=3.5.0->ipywidgets>=7.5.1->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (0.8.3)
Requirement already satisfied: Send2Trash in c:\users\antoi\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from notebook>=4.4.1->widgetsnbextension~=3.5.0->ipywidgets>=7.5.1->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (1.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: wcwidth in c:\users\antoi\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from prompt-toolkit!=3.0.0,!=3.0.1,<3.1.0,>=2.0.0->ipython>=4.0.0; python_version >= "3.3"->ipywidgets>=7.5.1->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (0.1.9)
Requirement already satisfied: parso<0.8.0,>=0.7.0 in c:\users\antoi\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from jedi>=0.10->ipython>=4.0.0; python_version >= "3.3"->ipywidgets>=7.5.1->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (0.7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyrsistent>=0.14.0 in c:\users\antoi\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from jsonschema!=2.5.0,>=2.4->nbformat>=4.2.0->ipywidgets>=7.5.1->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (0.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: importlib-metadata; python_version < "3.8" in c:\users\antoi\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from jsonschema!=2.5.0,>=2.4->nbformat>=4.2.0->ipywidgets>=7.5.1->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (1.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: entrypoints>=0.2.2 in c:\users\antoi\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from nbconvert->notebook>=4.4.1->widgetsnbextension~=3.5.0->ipywidgets>=7.5.1->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pandocfilters>=1.4.1 in c:\users\antoi\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from nbconvert->notebook>=4.4.1->widgetsnbextension~=3.5.0->ipywidgets>=7.5.1->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (1.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: mistune<2,>=0.8.1 in c:\users\antoi\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from nbconvert->notebook>=4.4.1->widgetsnbextension~=3.5.0->ipywidgets>=7.5.1->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (0.8.4)
Requirement already satisfied: testpath in c:\users\antoi\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from nbconvert->notebook>=4.4.1->widgetsnbextension~=3.5.0->ipywidgets>=7.5.1->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (0.4.4)
Requirement already satisfied: defusedxml in c:\users\antoi\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from nbconvert->notebook>=4.4.1->widgetsnbextension~=3.5.0->ipywidgets>=7.5.1->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (0.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: bleach in c:\users\antoi\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from nbconvert->notebook>=4.4.1->widgetsnbextension~=3.5.0->ipywidgets>=7.5.1->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (3.1.5)
Requirement already satisfied: pywinpty>=0.5; os_name == "nt" in c:\users\antoi\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from terminado>=0.8.1->notebook>=4.4.1->widgetsnbextension~=3.5.0->ipywidgets>=7.5.1->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (0.5.7)
Requirement already satisfied: zipp>=0.5 in c:\users\antoi\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from importlib-metadata; python_version < "3.8"->jsonschema!=2.5.0,>=2.4->nbformat>=4.2.0->ipywidgets>=7.5.1->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (3.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging in c:\users\antoi\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from bleach->nbconvert->notebook>=4.4.1->widgetsnbextension~=3.5.0->ipywidgets>=7.5.1->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (20.3)
Requirement already satisfied: webencodings in c:\users\antoi\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (from bleach->nbconvert->notebook>=4.4.1->widgetsnbextension~=3.5.0->ipywidgets>=7.5.1->pandas-profiling[notebook]) (0.5.1)

WARNING: You are using pip version 20.0.2; however, version 20.1.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'C:\Users\antoi\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-92ac6bedabf5> in <module>
      6 import scipy.stats as stats
      7 get_ipython().system('pip3 install pandas-profiling[notebook]')
----> 8 import pandas_profiling as pp
      9 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
     10 

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas_profiling'
```

Or it tells me that it that DLL load failed

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.900]
(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\antoi>jupyter notebook
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 6, in <module>
    from notebook.notebookapp import main
  File "C:\Users\antoi\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 62, in <module>
    from tornado import httpserver
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\httpserver.py", line 29, in <module>
    import ssl
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 98, in <module>
    import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?